# Kotlin - Create an ArrayList of random Integers of specified length?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an `ArrayList` like this :

```
var amplititudes : ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
```

I want to populate this with random Ints. How can I do this?

Comment: I tried Adding Java code in Kotiln using Streams but that is supported only on API  levels 24 and higher

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One option is to use the array constructor as following:

```
var amplititudes  = IntArray(10) { Random().nextInt() }.asList()
```

Another strategy is:

```
var amplititudes  = (1..10).map { Random().nextInt() }
```

**EDIT (OUTDATED!)**

*You no longer need to do this, as Kotlin will only create a single instance of Random.*

As suggested in the comment instead of creating an instance of `Random` each time it is better to initialize it once:

```
var ran = Random()
var amplititudes  = (1..10).map { ran.nextInt() }
```

Comment: This way you'll create a new `Random` instance for each element, which is not very efficient

Comment: For the sake of readers in 202x using Kotlin 1.5 and above, @user2340612's comment is no longer true (in fact, I'm not entirely sure it ever was). `Random` is a reference to a single instance of Random (declared as a companion object), so it doesn't create a new instance.

Comment: @k314159 in the past there used to be a default Random implementation that could be accessed calling methods on the companion object as described [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/random.md#default-random-number-generator)

Comment: I rolled back the last edit because it significantly changed the code: Kotlin's Random was used instead of Java's Random which turns it into a completely different answer. Only the OP should do such a change.

Answer (score 6):

Based to the answer of [@Md Johirul Islam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50581392/5558072) You can also use :

```
val from = 0
val to = 11
val random = Random
var amplititudes  = IntArray(10) { random.nextInt(to - from) +  from }.asList()
```

in this solution you can specify the range of ints that you want, from 0 to 10 for example

Answer (score 5):

Since Kotlin 1.3 was released there is no need to use Java's [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) which would restrict your code to the JVM. Instead [`kotlin.random.Random`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) was introduced which is available on all platforms that support Kotlin.

```
val amplititudes  = IntArray(10) { Random.nextInt() }.asList()
```

Since you work with a companion object, you don't need to worry about instanting a `Random` object each iteration (like it was with the Java one that you would have had to put in a variable).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
val amplitudes = ThreadLocalRandom.current().let { rnd ->
    IntArray(5) { rnd.nextInt() }
}
```

Or this:

```
val amplitudes = ThreadLocalRandom.current().let { rnd ->
    (0..5).map { rnd.nextInt() }.toIntArray()
}
```

Comment: Using `let` is very "kotlin-style' IMHO. It could be also `Random().let { ... }`, couldn't it?

Comment: Yes you can use the normal Random class in that case

Comment: What is the importance of ThreadLocalRandom when compared to other methods mentioned in other answers?

Comment: Taken from the docs "When applicable, use of ThreadLocalRandom rather than shared Random objects in concurrent programs will typically encounter much less overhead and contention." -> in this case it's rather unimportant. What is important though: I instantiate it only once instead of multiple times using the scope function let

Comment: Repeated calls of `ThreadLocalRandom.get()` will yield the same instance anyway.

Comment: Yeah that is true but I'd recommend the shown usage instead of an unnecessary local variable for it

Comment: You need neither `let` nor a local var if you call `ThreadLocalRandom.get()` repeatedly. OTOH there's still some small overhead you eliminate by calling it only once, the lookup code.

Comment: I can see that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To generate a random number of specified length of List and between certain limits, use:

```
val rnds = (1..10).map { (0..130).random() }
```

Where `(1..0)` -> return list of 10 items
`(0..130)` -> return random number between given range

Answer (score 0):

At this time, is not specified in your question the range of the Ints and how many do you need.

So I restrict the case to [n,m] interval, and I suppose you want all the m-n+1 elements.

Taking advantage of method shuffle of ArrayList,

```
var shuffledList = ArrayList((n..m).toList())
shuffledList.shuffle()
```